Appropriate defining equations for Haskell functions
The task is to give appropriate defining equations for the following functions:

curry :: ((a, b) → c) → a → b → c

uncurry :: (a → b → c) → (a, b) → c

curry takes one function and two types (a,b) and returns c.

uncurry takes two functions and returns c.


Im actually not sure what to do at this point. Can someone help?
Thanks in advance!

With what are you struggling?

4 is wrong: uncurry does not take two functions. It's unclear what is expected for 3 and 4 since you already had to define curry and uncurry in 1 and 2.

Start with writing a definition for curry, this will look like:
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
curry f x y = …
so here f has type (a, b) -> c, and x and y have types a and b respectively. Now look how you can combine f, x and y to produce something that has type c. Based on the types of f, x and y, there is only one sensical way to do this where we use all variables.
The same with uncurry:
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
uncurry f (x, y) = …

On top of the suggestion given by Willem, I would also recommend using holes to fill a partial solution, and read the messages from the compiler.
To add a hole, use _ on the point(s) you do not know yet how to complete. For instance,
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
curry f x y = _

makes the compiler report:
Found hole: _ :: c
Relevant bindings include
    y :: b
    x :: a
    f :: (a, b) -> c

In this way the compiler is telling you that the hole must be filled with something of type c, and that we can use variables y,x,f with those types to fill the hole with an expression.
c is the return type of function f, so we might try to apply f to something. Let's replace the hole with a function application f _ (which involves a new hole, since we do not know yet what should be the argument for f).
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
curry f x y = f _

Now the compiler reports:
Found hole: _ :: (a, b)
Relevant bindings include
    y :: b
    x :: a
    f :: (a, b) -> c

You should now be able to complete the exercise by filling the last hole with the above information. All you need is writing a value of type (a, b) using the variables above.
